# trying to build apk for android and get npm errors

Tags: node.js, git, cordova, powershell, ionic-framework

Hi when i try to run this command `ionic cordova build android --release`
I get the error below

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

- I reinstalled ionic, Cordova still did not work
- I reinstalled nodeJS
- I also uninstalled the android platform and reinstalled it and it still did not work.
- I tried installing cordova-plugin-email-composer
- I also tried different programs such as git bash, PowerShell and command prompt

  ```
  (truncated) ... ww/js/services.js
  File www/js/services.js has no errors.
  -----------------------------------------
  Linting www/js/views.js
  File www/js/views.js has no errors.
  -----------------------------------------
  Discovered plugin "com.rjfun.cordova.iad" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
  Failed to restore plugin "com.rjfun.cordova.iad" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error:

  Failed to fetch plugin com.rjfun.cordova.iad@^2.0.4 via registry.
  Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
  Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
  npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program
  Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "com.rjfun.cordova.iad@2.0.4"
  npm ERR! node v6.11.2
  npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
  npm ERR! code E404

  npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/com.rjfun.cordova.iad
  npm ERR! 404
  npm ERR! 404  'com.rjfun.cordova.iad' is not in the npm registry.
  npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
  npm ERR! 404
  npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
  npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

  npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
  npm ERR!     C:\Users\fartsstinksodontfart\Desktop\newiconic\hoydesigndiifferent\node_modules\npm-debug.log
  Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-email-composer" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
  Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-email-composer" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again.

  Error: Failed to fetch plugin
  cordova-plugin-email-composer@https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git#0.8.2 via registry.
  Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
  Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  npm ERR! git clone
  C:\Users\fartsstinksodontfart\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-katzer-cordova-plugin- email-composer-git-0-8-2-1181afa8
  C:\Users\FARTSS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-10508-f9448953\git-cache-5f8d071e\cab303daada1d86579b6c76354b8333ae5d1a efe:
  Cloning into
  'C:\Users\FARTSS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-10508-f9448953\git-cache-5f8d071e\cab303daada1d86579b6c76354b8333ae5d1 aefe'...
  npm ERR! git clone
  C:\Users\fartsstinksodontfart\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-katzer-cordova-plugin- email-composer-git-0-8-2-1181afa8
  C:\Users\FARTSS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-10508-f9448953\git-cache-5f8d071e\cab303daada1d86579b6c76354b8333ae5d1a efe:
  error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
  npm ERR! git clone
  C:\Users\fartsstinksodontfart\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-katzer-cordova-plugin- email-composer-git-0-8-2-1181afa8
  C:\Users\FARTSS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-10508-f9448953\git-cache-5f8d071e\cab303daada1d86579b6c76354b8333ae5d1a efe:
  fatal: unable to fork
  npm ERR! git clone
  C:\Users\fartsstinksodontfart\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-katzer-cordova-plugin- email-composer-git-0-8-2-1181afa8
  C:\Users\FARTSS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-10508-f9448953\git-cache-5f8d071e\cab303daada1d86579b6c76354b8333ae5d1a efe:

  npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
  npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program
  Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
  "cordova-plugin-email-composer@https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git#0.8.2"
  npm ERR! node v6.11.2
  npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
  npm ERR! code 128

  npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone
  C:\Users\fartsstinksodontfart\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-katzer-cordova-plugin- email-composer-git-0-8-2-1181afa8
  C:\Users\FARTSS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-10508-f9448953\git-cache-5f8d071e\cab303daada1d86579b6c76354b8333ae5d1a efe
  npm ERR! Cloning into
  'C:\Users\FARTSS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-10508-f9448953\git-cache-5f8d071e\cab303daada1d86579b6c76354b8333ae5d1 aefe'...
  npm ERR! error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
  npm ERR! fatal: unable to fork
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
  npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

  npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
  npm ERR!     C:\Users\fartsstinksodontfart\Desktop\newiconic\hoydesigndiifferent\node_modules\npm-debug.log
  Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
  C:\Users\fartsstinksodontfart\Desktop\newiconic\hoydesigndiifferent\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.j s
  C:\Users\fartsstinksodontfart\Desktop\newiconic\hoydesigndiifferent
  add to body class: platform-android
  Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
  C:\Users\fartsstinksodontfart\Desktop\newiconic\hoydesigndiifferent\hooks\after_prepare\020_remove_sass_from_pla tforms.js
  C:\Users\fartsstinksodontfart\Desktop\newiconic\hoydesigndiifferent
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have this plugin only in your `config.xml`. Removing and adding the plugin using the **CLI** should fix the problem.it will automatically add it to `plugins/fetch.json` file.

```
cordova plugin rm com.rjfun.cordova.iad
cordova plugin add com.rjfun.cordova.iad
```

if this not work.try deleting `node_modules` directory and then `npm install`

Comment: what version of node should i have?

Comment: the v8.4.0 Current
Latest Features?

Comment: any latest versions,but it's not node's problem. Up-vote or mark as answer if this helps you.